# How to Ignore Overriding

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding

Code first - question later

```java
class A {
    int value() { return 1; }   //The value

    int getThisValue() { return this.value(); }  //gives back the overridden value
    int getValue() { return value(); }           //this too

    int getSuperValue() { return value(); }     //for overriding in B
    final int getSuperValue2() { return getSuperValue(); }  
    //Here I get the not-overridden value
    //TODO: simplify the process of getting the un-overridden value

}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    final int getSuperValue() { return super.value(); }  //returns the correct value
}

public class Test extends B{
    @Override
    int value() { return 3; }    //overriding the value

    public static void main(String[] args) {  //output
        Test test = new Test();

        System.out.println("getValue(): " + test.getValue());                 //3
        System.out.println("getThisValue(): " + test.getThisValue());         //3
        System.out.println("getSuperValue(): " + test.getSuperValue());       //1
        System.out.println("getSuperValue2(): " + test.getSuperValue2());     //1
    }
}
```

I have `A` class, in which I access `value`.
This `value` gets overridden
**-> I want to access the un-overrridden `value` in `A`**
My Question: Is *getSuperValue2()* the only way get the un-overridden `value` or is there another way?

I want to know if I can protect my Code, by only accessing Code I know, but making my code overrideable for those, that want to change the functionality a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed no way once a subclass starts overriding. That's by design - you don't get to refer to "The implementation of the `getValue()` method the way class A does it", that's the wrong mental model. You merely get to refer to the notion of "the implementation of the `getValue()` method the way this object does it" (note the difference: Think 'objects', not 'classes'). Once we talk solely about 'the impl from this object', then the idea of "But I want the unoverridden value" no longer makes any sense, hence *why* you can't do it.

> want to know if I can protect my Code

Yeah of course. Just mark the method `final`! This is a sometimes-observed pattern:

```
public class Parent {
   public final void init() {
     childInit();
     doStuffThatChildClassesCannotStopFromHappening();
   }

   protected void childInit() {
     // does nothing - child classes can override if they wish
   }
}
```